# How to convert string to wchar* in unicode

Tags: c++, unicode, ansi-c

I'm trying to define a function like this:

```
#ifdef _UNICODE
LPCTSTR A2T(const string& str); 
#else
#define A2T
#endif
```

If my project is in Ansi, than A2T(str) is str itself. When my project is in unicode A2T(str) return a LPCTST type

Comment: The first thing you need to figure out is which character set the conversion should use. Nobody can tell you which character you have to use, you have to figure it out yourself. If you cannot answer this question, or you have no idea what this is, then you will not be able to do this.

Comment: I want to realise a general code, that is whatever character set the compiler using, ansi or unicode, my code will not need to be modified. And  A2T can always return a LPCTSTR.

Comment: Why are you even dealing with TCHAR? That is only needed for Win9x/ME. Are you still supporting those versions?  If no, you should be using Unicode for everything, don't set the compiler to Ansi at all anymore.

Comment: Using the `_T` stuff for new code is irrational. Your new programs will not be run in Windows 9x. Code for Unicode only.

Answer (score 1):

When `UNICODE` is defined, `LPCTSTR` is an alias for `const wchar_t*`, otherwise it is an alias for `const char*`.

Your current macro returns `const wchar_t*` for Unicode, but returns `std::string` for Ansi.  That doesn't make sense. You wouldn't be able to use `A2T()` consistently everywhere `LPCTSTR` is expected. The code would not even compile for Ansi since a `std::string` cannot be assigned directly to a `char*`. For Unicode, the code would compile, but you would have a memory leak since a conversion from `std:string` to `wchar_t*` requires a dynamic memory allocation that you have to free eventually.

A better option is to have `A2T()` return `std::wstring` for Unicode, and `std::string` for Ansi:

```
#ifdef UNICODE
std::wstring A2T(const string& str)
{
    std::wstring result;
    // do the conversion from Ansi to Unicode as needed...
    // MultiByteToWideChar(), std::wstring_convert, etc...
    return result;
}
#else
std::string A2T(const string& str)
{
    return str;
}
#endif
```

Alternatively:

```
std::basic_string<TCHAR> A2T(const string& str)
{
    #ifdef UNICODE
    std::wstring result;
    // do the conversion from Ansi to Unicode as needed...
    // MultiByteToWideChar(), std::wstring_convert, etc...
    return result;
    #else
    return str;
    #endif
}
```

Either way, you get the automatic memory management you need after conversion, and you can use `A2T()` consistently in both Ansi and Unicode (when passing the return value of `A2T(str)` to a `LPCTSTR`, you can use `A2T(str).c_str()`).

Or, you could simply forget writing your own function and just use the existing `A2CT()` function or `CA2CT` class that is already available in MFC/ATL:

[ATL and MFC String Conversion Macros](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87zae4a3.aspx)